# Angular FormControl: How do I apply a class or attribute to the underlying DOM element?

Tags: angular

A few days ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282035/angular-validators-can-i-add-styling-to-form-elements-based-on-their-validators). After learning a bit more, I think I've got an idea for a solution, but there's still one piece of it that I can't figure out how to do. So I'm re-stating my question to narrow it down to that last piece.

I have a controller that adds validators to form controls based on a database configuration that can change (e.g. which fields are required, min/max values, etc), so the validation state of each particular form control is not known at development time. I also have a requirement to add an asterisk to the labels of all required fields.

Since the controller code that adds the validators already has access to the FormControl, I think the way I need to do this is to take that FormControl and add a class or attribute to its underlying DOM element so that the CSS can apply the asterisk automatically. Is there any way to do that programmatically? I don't see anything in the FormControl that lets me access its underlying DOM element, and Angular doesn't add any persistent classes or attributes to the DOM (just ng-invalid if the field has been touched and left blank).

In various HTML files:

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <md-input-container>
      <!-- This needs a class or attribute added to it if the database says it's required -->
      <input mdInput type="text" placeholder="name" formControlName="name">
    <md-input-container>
    <!-- more inputs here -->
  </form>
</div>
```

In my controller:

```
generateValidators(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  // Go get the database configuration for which fields should have
  // validators, then apply appropriate validators
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(fieldName) => {
    let validators = [];
    if(database configuration indicates this field is required) {
      validators.push(Validators.required);
      // ****** I'd like to add the class/attribute to the DOM here ******
    }
    if(database configuration indicates this field has a max length) {
      validators.push(Validators.maxLength(length));
    }
    // etc.
    formGroup.controls[fieldName].setValidators(validators);
  }
}
```

In my CSS:

```
.required:after { content:" *"; }
```

I'm using Forms version 4.1.0 and Material version 2.0.0-beta.8, if that helps.

Comment: I'm missing something. Why can't you use ngClass to add the classes to the labels programatically?

Comment: I have a workaround that I mentioned in my earlier question. Basically I added an isRequired(string) method to each of my controllers, which looks through the same database configuration to see if the named field is required and adds the required attribute. I could do the same with ngClass. However, this is something that would need to be added to every field in every HTML file, with multiple developers needing to adhere to that. It's just too easy to have that break. That's why I'm looking for a centralized, automatic way to do it.